# AutoFill dates but skip weekends

Tags: google-sheets

I need to auto fill the some dates which is easy and I know how to do.  However, I do not know how to do this skipping the weekends.  I want it to auto fill skipping weekends and jumping to Monday.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This can be done with a conditional statement involving [`WEEKDAY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092985)

Let's say you put 5/7/2015 in A2, and the conditional formula

```
=IF(WEEKDAY(A2)=6,A2+3,A2+1)
```

in A3. (Weekday=6 means Friday, after which two days are skipped). Dragging this down you'll see

```
5/7/2015
5/8/2015
5/11/2015
5/12/2015
5/13/2015
5/14/2015
5/15/2015
5/18/2015
```

and so on.

Comment: How do you account for an array of holidays too?

Answer (score 5):

The following formula for A1:A7

```
=WORKDAY.INTL("1/05/2015",Row(),"0000011")
```

returns

```
Tuesday, January 6, 2015  
Wednesday, January 7, 2015  
Thursday, January 8, 2015  
Friday, January 9, 2015  
Monday, January 12, 2015  
Tuesday, January 13, 2015  
Wednesday, January 14, 2015
```

**Reference**
[WORKDAY.INTL - Docs Editor Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3294972?hl=en)